# Path of a nozzle crosses over itself

Tags: diy-3d-printer, nozzle, layer-height

I built my first printer couple of days ago. I started printing small models (20x20 mm max.) and everything was alright at first. However, when I tried to print a bit larger models, I started facing a problem. The nozzle keeps hitting the path of a previous layer or even current layer. That then causes jams, and the whole layer shifts 5-10 mm in the X or Y direction. I tried using different layer heights (from 0.08 mm to 0.44 mm), adjusting the speed of print but that did not help.

Comment: Can you tell us what printer you're using? Is it a clone? What Marlin version are you using? Can you also put in what your settings are and which slicer you're using?

Comment: I'm am using a DIY Cartesian based 3D printer, with latest versions of marlin and slic3r. I am using pronterface to run the G-code. I have T8 threaded rods with 8mm pitch for the z axis and two GT2 belts for the X and Y axis. I also have 0.4mm nozzle with 1.75mm filament. I tried a few different Slic3r settings:
Layer height: 0.08 - 0.44mm
Fill density: 20%-70%
Fill pattern: Triangles, rectilinear and honecomb

Comment: The heat is set to 205 degrees for the extruder and 40 degrees for the heatbed (It says so on the fillament packing)

Comment: Usually, when you have a problem like what you're saying, the problem lies with how you are slicing it, not with the machine itself. I wouldn't be looking at layer height or stuff like that, but how does the slicer make its path. I believe slic3r allows you to see the path virtually before you try to print something. You might want to take a look at it from that direction to see if you can tell what's causing the issues.

Comment: Please back this up with pictures of the failed print, sliced print in the slicer, link to model.

Comment: I know of no slicing software which produces crossovers in a given layer.  My guess is you're either not getting sufficient adhesion to the bed or insufficient Z-axis motion per layer.

Comment: It could be the Motors are stalling and missing steps. Home the Z Axis, send it to the top limit, then send it back to 0. Does it return to the correct location?

Comment: At my printer (Anet A8) if there is a crossover it just runs over this, whit noise and jerking, but it stays in the programmed path. Layer shifts by this problem sounds like the motors just missing steps aka. to less power. IDK but some printers have potentiometers for the motors so you can regulate the power so they are less noisy or more powerfull, and maybe noisless motors sounds good in the first place but are not powerfull enough to handle little resistance.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: FWIW, I arrived at this question because I have the same issue. During the first layer of the print, a loop is printed approximately the size and shape of the base of the print, but then a brim is printed over that, but for the same layer. This results in crossing of the path, and defects where the crossings happen (the current path breaks, and sometimes the path being crossed gets dragged). This is on a brand new Prusa Mk3.